# Android Studio this error 3 Java when returning to Run the application

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Run the application by pressing returning this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myproject:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

My project has the lib facebook sdk and wheellib.
I realized that Android Studio is a long time processing the Gradle and after that displays this error and the application never starts (Run)

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'br.com.myproject'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':wheellib')
    compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Apparently your solution worked, but still the Android Studio okay slow for a gradle build. There is a way to improve the speed?
EDIT - After a few Run, presented the same mistake. I changed the Java 1.8 to 1.7 and even then the error is being displayed for the 1.8 that returns 3. The stacktrace is bringing me:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my build.gradle and work! Added dexOptions:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'br.com.myproject'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':wheellib')
    compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run this command at your terminal:

```
your-project-directory:$> gradle build --info --stacktrace
```

Then you will see the exactly moment that te gradle task fail.

I believe that the problem is that you are probably facing the 64k method limit.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem today too, it was in SDK that needs JDK 1_7 only ! I add it in gradle

```
compileOptions {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

then change yours HOME_JAVA on computer to JDK version 1_7 and change Java version in Android Studios Project structure to 1_7 that is all i do.
You may just check compatibility all yours JDK  requirements or it may be 64+ methods problem too...